${a_n}$: an arithmetic progression $\sum_{x_n=1}^{x_{n+1}}{\sum_{x_{n-1}=1}^{x_{n}}{\dots\sum_{x_1=1}^{x_2}{a_{x_1}}}}$?
Question) Prove that
${a_n}:  \text{arithmetic progression}$,
$$\sum_{x_n=1}^{x_{n+1}}{\sum_{x_{n-1}=1}^{x_{n}}{\dots\sum_{x_1=1}^{x_2}{a_{x_1}}}} = \frac{\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}(x_{n+1}+i)}{n!}\cdot\frac{na_1+a_{x_{n+1}}}{n+1}$$
Example)
$$\begin{align*}
n&=1: &\sum_{x_1=1}^{x_2}{a_{x_1}} &= a_1+a_2+\dots +a_{x_2}= x_2\cdot\frac{a_1+a_{x_2}}{2}\\
n&=2:  &\sum_{x_2=1}^{x_3}\left(\sum_{x_1=1}^{x_2}{a_{x_1}}\right) &= \sum_{x_2=1}^{x_3}(a_1+a_2+\dots +a_{x_2})\\
&&&= (a_1)+(a_1+a_2)+\dots+(a_1+a_2+\dots +a_{x_3})\\
&&&= \frac{x_3(x_3+1)}{2!}\cdot\frac{2a_1+a_{x_3}}{3}\\
\end{align*}$$
This is the same question :
$$\text{Let }\ C_k = \frac{\prod_{i=0}^{k-2}(x_k+i)}{(k-1)!}$$
$$\sum_{x_n=1}^{x_{n+1}}{C_n\cdot\frac{(n-1)a_1+a_{x_n}}{n}} = C_{n+1}\cdot\frac{na_1+a_{x_{n+1}}}{n+1}$$ where $n\in\mathbb N, n\ge1$. (In particular, $C_1 = 1$ for the empty products)
Example)
$$\begin{align*}
n&=1: &\sum_{x_1=1}^{x_2}{1\cdot\frac{a_{x_1}}{1}} &= x_2\cdot\frac{a_1+a_{x_2}}{2}\\
n&=2:\ &\sum_{x_2=1}^{x_3}{x_2\cdot\frac{a_1+a_{x_2}}{2}} &= \frac{x_3{(x_3+1)}}{2!}\cdot\frac{2a_1+a_{x_3}}{3}\\
n&=3:\ &\sum_{x_3=1}^{x_4}{\frac{x_3{(x_3+1)}}{2}\cdot\frac{2a_1+a_{x_3}}{3}} &= \frac{x_4{(x_4+1)(x_4+2)}}{3!}\cdot\frac{3a_1+a_{x_4}}{4}\\
\end{align*}$$
(Properties of arithmetic sequences)
I showed the same question of different form because the latter one shows the meaning of the equation better; $C_n$ is number of terms in a sequence and $\frac{(n-1)a_1+a_{x_n}}{n}$ is the average of the sequence. but it is hard to prove this anyway. I tried with induction but it was to complicated. How do I solve this problem?
solution)
$$C_n=\binom{n+x_n-2}{n-1}$$
Thus the expression can be shown as
$$\sum_{x_n=1}^{x_{n+1}}{\binom{n+x_n-2}{n-1}\cdot\frac{(n-1)a_1+a_{x_n}}{n}}$$
Let $a_{x_n}=a_1+(x_n-1)d$ where $d$ is common difference.
$\frac{(n-1)a_1+a_{x_n}}{n}=a_1+\frac{(x_n-1)d}{n}$
Since$$\sum_{x_n=1}^{x_{n+1}}{C_n}=C_{n+1} \ \text{(Hockey Stick Identity)}$$
$$\therefore\sum_{x_n=1}^{x_{n+1}}{\binom{n+x_n-2}{n-1}\cdot\frac{(n-1)a_1+a_{x_n}}{n}}=a_1\cdot{C_{n+1}}+ \sum_{x_n=1}^{x_{n+1}}{\frac{(x_n-1)d}{n}\cdot{C_n}}= a_1\cdot{C_{n+1}}+ \sum_{x_n=1}^{x_{n+1}}{d\cdot{\binom{n+x_n-2}{n}}}=a_1\cdot{C_{n+1}}+d\cdot{C_{n+1}\cdot{\frac{x_{n+1}-1}{n+1}}}= RHS$$

Can you clarify what it means to sum from $x_1 = 1$ to $x_2$ of $a x_1$?  IE Isn't $x_1$ some fixed variable (which is my reading of it). $\quad$ So, if $ax_1$ is fixed, then the LHS is some multiple of $ax_1$, so it seems very unlikely to be equal to the RHS. Perhaps there should be a bunch of $i, j$ terms in the summation? $\quad$ Also,

No that equation is correct I added some examples when n=1,2,3

I am guessing that you want something like "Sum from $k= x_1$ to $x_2$ of $ax_{\color{red}{k}} $.

Your $n = 2$ example makes no sense to me. Can you write out the $n = 1$ example, so that I can understand what your equation actually is? My sense is that you know what you want but are not writing it down correctly, hence the miscommunication.

Sum from $x_1=1$to $x_2$of $a_{x_1}$ is same to Sum from $n=1$to $x_2$of $a_n$

I want sum of sum of... sum of arthimetic progression {a_n} so I write like this.

No they are not the same. You claim that $x_1 = 1$ is the same as $n= 1$? That's clearly not true. $\quad$ I agree that that "sum form $n = 1$ to $ x_2$ of $a_n$ is more aligned with your statements. But even then, you need to figure out what the next layer of summation is, because you cannot do another "sum from $ n = 1 $ to $x_3$" since you have  double notation on $n$. $\quad$ I suspect what you want is $ \sum_{j=x_2}^{x_3} \sum_{n=1}^j  a_{x_n} $. (read the indices carefully.)

$x_1=1$ of ${a_{x_1}}$ is the same as $n=1$ of ${a_n}$

I reviewed my question several times but I couldn't found any problem.. That expression is what I want to say.

There is n=1,2,3 example so it would be helpful.

I made more examples.

@CalvinLin I read that $n$ and $x_{n+1}$ are given fixed variables, while all $x_1, x_2,\ldots, x_n$ are indices of summation and are not fixed.

While editing the post, I considered including the alternative definition $$C_k = \binom{x_k+k-2}{k-1}.$$ Since you asked about $C_n$ and the number of terms, this can be explained by the number of non-decreasing sequences $1\le x_1 \le x_2 \le \ldots \le x_n \le x_{n+1}$ (where $x_{n+1}$ is already fixed), and hence the $C_{n+1} = \binom{x_{n+1}+n-1}{n}$ on the RHS.

the value of the expression is independent to the value of $x_1,\dots,x_{n-1}$ since whatever the value is, $x_i$ starts 1 by next summation

Indeed, I considered $x_1,\dots,x_{n-1}$ cannot be given specific value. They are just letters to make the final sum of $x_{n-1}$ from 1 to ${x_n}$.

I understand that, I was mentioning the correspondence between the $a$-terms and those non-decreasing sequences. For example the fixed $n=2$ and $x_3=3$, there are $6$ $a$-terms: $$a_1+a_1+a_2+a_1+a_2+a_3$$
corresponding to $6$ non-decreasing $2$-sequences between $1$ and $3$ inclusive: $$(x_1,x_2) \in {(1,1), (1,2), (2,2), (1,3), (2,3), (3,3)}$$

Based on the combinatorial argument for the simple arithmetic sequence $(i)_{i}$, then by letting $a_i = a_0 + id$,
$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{x_n=1}^{x_{n+1}}{\sum_{x_{n-1}=1}^{x_{n}}{\cdots\sum_{x_1=1}^{x_2}{(a_0+x_1 d)}}} &= \sum_{x_n=1}^{x_{n+1}}{\sum_{x_{n-1}=1}^{x_{n}}{\cdots\sum_{x_1=1}^{x_2}{\left(a_0+\sum_{x_0=1}^{x_1}d\right)}}}\
&= \binom{x_{n+1}+n-1}{n}a_0 + \binom{x_{n+1}+n}{n+1}d
\end{align*}$$
